# Getting slmgr.vbs output, and/or Windows licensing status reports across multiple servers

Tags: windows, licensing, reporting

I've got a number of Windows Servers that I've recently taken ownership on, and I'm looking to do a report on how these are licensed. I know it's a mix between KMS and MAK licensing, but I'm trying to find a way of generating a report showing me the licensing status, or the equivalent output of `slmgr.vbs /dli` for each server.

All of these machines are managed with SCCM2012, so I thought there would be a way of getting this information from there, but I can't find it.

Short of writing a `psexec` script, is there a better way of getting this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slgmr` isn't the best tool for this. You can inventory the licensing for your current operating systems using the [VAMT 2.0 tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11936) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a doityourself approach in powershell (I was for a fleet of dev machines) that could integrate try this as a staring point to gather an object based value out of the strings that slmgr provides. You need to use cscript to get output to console that you can capture.

```
$results=invoke-command "computer1","computer2" {
$license=[ordered] @{};
cscript C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /dlv all |?{$_ -match ":"} | foreach-object {$row=$_ -split ":";$license.$($row[0])=$row[1]}
new-object -type pscustomobject -property $license
}
$results | Out-GridView
```